# Computer Power Supply Testing Safety

Tags: power-supply, safety, repair, testing

I have a 750 watt ATX power supply that I will be testing with a multimeter to make sure the right voltages are present. How can I make sure that I do this safely? Is there anything that's threatening my safety that I should be aware of before I go prodding away at the leads?

Is the power that the PSU provides through its connectors enough to cause injury?

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect the power supply is putting out the wrong voltages? If you have a defective PS, it may put out a different voltage with no load (only the meter connected) vs. connected to real loads (motherboard, drives, etc.). A normal ATX power supply should give the correct voltage up to current limits but if there is a problem, who knows.

Comment: I am troubleshooting an issue where the computer gives blue screens when it resumes(occasionally). Everything points to a hardware issue, though I have performed diagnostics on the ram and hard disk. At this point, I'm just moving through the process of elimination. I'm just hoping that a problem will appear when I check the voltages with no load. Otherwise I'll just go ahead and RMA the motherboard and hope that the problem is fixed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Many novices seem to want to measure the current output capability of power supplies by setting their meter to read current, then connecting it directly across the power supply terminals. **YOU MUST NEVER CONNECT AN AMMETER DIRECTLY ACROSS A POWER SUPPLY**  Doing so will cause very large currents to flow, and may permanently damage the meter, power supply, **or user**!

If you keep the meter in voltage mode, and are careful to not short the test leads or power supply wiring, you should be able to measure the supply voltages without any hazard.

Many PC power supplies (and other switch-mode supplies) require a minimum load to operate correctly.  Be sure you have a suitable load connected during your tests (or any time the supply is on.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you screw up. The 5V rails in particular have double-digit currents, so be triply sure that your DMM is in voltage mode before measuring each time.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is necessary? I would like to understand what makes this a crucial part of maintaining a proper level of safety. Is it because there is a fuse that will blow and protect me from the high current or something? Can you please provide further explanation or reading material explaining this aspect of electrical safety. A Google search doesn't yield as many results as I'd like.

Comment: The very high input impedance of the DMM in voltage mode will prevent much current from flowing.

Comment: Let's say you try to measure the 5V output and you accidentally have your DVM set for current measurement. The fuse in the meter should blow before much power can be delivered. However, if someone, in the past, bypassed the fuse or you have a super-cheapo meter,you may have the meter blow up in your face.

Comment: Sooo... I should wear safety glasses?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to offer a frame challenge answer. From your comments it seems that even if the PSU did have a hardware fault you wouldn't have the ability to fully diagnose / repair it. Perhaps a simpler way of diagnosing this is just to try a different PSU and see if the PC works? Diagnosing a hardware fault will take far more than checking voltages are present. It is a good starting point but its knowing what to do with it after

Alternatively Have you considered using an off the shelf PSU tester such as this?
[Amazon Link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Boladge-Detection-Display-Computer-Supply/dp/B073M2FFJ4/ref=sr_1_3?adgrpid=54813351764&gclid=CjwKCAjwx_boBRA9EiwA4kIELn_wO0b4AU5WhqkwFNmU8K12U6dQRKOMTg8296odGuSOWaXi7XUWWBoCQXQQAvD_BwE&hvadid=259082879242&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9045303&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=14053004368574030630&hvtargid=aud-612745333569%3Akwd-296118438849&hydadcr=28149_1752716&keywords=atx%20psu%20tester&qid=1562232301&s=gateway&sr=8-3)